# Vimeo API froogaloop into HTML 5 player without vimeo controls

Tags: api, controls, customization, vimeo, froogaloop

I have to use Vimeo API froogaloop to play a video on my website but I want to customize the player... Unfortunately I can't remove the controls.

So I want to use Video flux from Vimeo into another player which I can customize myself.

Do you have any ideas ? Is it possible ?